# Hight Chart Dynamic Json Value is not loading in Series Data Section but Static Value is Loading Finely

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

Hi I have one issue i was creating one HighChart in this Static values to the series data section is working finely. but The same type value from a dynamic section is not showing.

```
    function getusercategorygraph()
{
    $.getJSON('config/alumniusermodes.php',function(data){ 
        //alert(json);
        //alert($.parseJSON(data));
        //alert(obj);
        var finaldata = '[';
        var tmp = '';
        var chart;
        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            finaldata += '{';
            $.each(value, function( index, value ) {
                //alert(index);
                if(index === 'name')
                {
                    tmp = " " + index + " : '" + value + "', "; 
                }
                else
                {
                   tmp = " " + index + " : " + value + ", ";  
                }
                finaldata += tmp;
                //alert("finaldata: " + finaldata);
            });
            finaldata+='},';             
        });
        finaldata +=']';
        //alert(finaldata);        
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
           /* backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                   [0, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'],
                   [1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)']
                ]
             },*/
            renderTo : 'user-count',
            type: 'column',                    
            },
            title: {                                                
                text: 'Alumni Users By Category Analytics'
            },                                            
            xAxis: {
                color:'#0077CC',
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number of Alumni Members'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y} Members'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} Members</b><br/>'
            },

            series: [{
                name: "Alumni Type",
                colorByPoint: true,
                //sdata: [{ name : 'Standard',  y : 52, },{ name : 'Silver',  y : 24, },{ name : 'Gold',  y : 20, },{ name : 'Platinum',  y : 6, },]
                data: [{ name : 'Standard',  y : 52, },{ name : 'Silver',  y : 24, },{ name : 'Gold',  y : 20, },{ name : 'Platinum',  y : 6, },]
                //data : finaldata,
            }],        
        });
        ///chart.series[2].data.push(finaldata);
    });
}
```

i am getting final data like this only

[{ name : 'Standard',  y : 52, },{ name : 'Silver',  y : 24, },{ name : 'Gold',  y : 20, },{ name : 'Platinum',  y : 6, },]

but i cant load that in this graph but when paste same value in static mode its showing correctly.

now its showinng a blank section only.
I am new to HighCharts Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i Found this as For My Query.

```
   var finaldata = [];
        $.getJSON('config/alumniusermodes.php',function(data){ 
            // Create a new array
            var finaldata = [];
            var chart;
            var categories = [];
            var tools = [];        
            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {            
                var currentItem = {}
                finaldata.push({
                        name: value.name,
                    y: parseFloat(value.y)
                });            
             });       

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({        
                chart: {              
                    renderTo : 'user-count',
                    type: 'column',                    
                },
                title: {                                                
                    text: 'Alumni Users By Category Analytics'
                },                                            
                xAxis: {
                    color:'#0077CC',                
                    categories: categories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total Number of Alumni Members'
                    }

                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y} Members'
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} Members</b><br/>'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: "Alumni Type",
                    colorByPoint: true,               
                    data : finaldata,
                }],
            });         
        });
```

This is my right coding which solved my issue

Comment: This has saved my time. After looking for a solution over 18hrs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating finaldata as a *string*, when you want to produce an *array*. You should have better luck with something like this:

```
// Create a new array
var finaldata = []
var chart;

// Perform your operations
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
    // Create a new hash
    var currentItem = {}

    // Create the proper values in your hash
    $.each(value, function( index, value ) {
        currentItem[index] = value;  
    });

    // Push the new hash to the array
    finaldata += currentItem;
 });
```

If all of your data is being passed in a way that your old code successfully created the string you shared, then this should build the object for which you are looking.

To test this you may first want to try leaving your code exactly how it is, and parsing the string to JSON:

```
// Use this instead of 'data : finaldata'
data: JSON.parse( finaldata ),
```

This will try to turn your string into the objects on which you are trying to operate. That said, it would be in poor form to practice building an array via string manipulation. I would very strongly encourage you to follow the first approach I detailed.

Comment: Its Not working when i alert final data its coming like this. [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]. and graph is showing empty.

Comment: And Even the x axis is also showing nothing. it have to show the categories

Comment: @KrishnakumarKU Could you post live example - like jsFiddle - with hard coded exemplary data?